# Are $C$, $D$ and $E$ collinear?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

---

Sorry for the picture. I really could not draw this in Geogebra. I want to find the length of $AC$. I assumed that $C$, $D$ and $E$ are collinear and solved it trivially using similar triangles. However, is the information sufficient to prove that $C$, $D$ and $E$ are collinear? If I assume they are collinear then I get $AC=16/3$.

For example, the diagram may look like this:

[image]

Comment: They will be collinear iff $C$ is the center of similitude of both the circle which clearly happens only when $C=\infty_{AA}$

Comment: Do you mean 'are A,E and D collinear'?

Comment: @JMP I guess he is referring to 1st diagram.

Comment: I am referring to the 1st diagram

Comment: @Anand Could you please explain the notation and how you come to this conclusion?

Comment: And if they are not collinear then how can we solve for the value of $AC$?

Comment: @PopularPower As $AC$ is tangent to both the circles, we get that the point $P = AC\cap DE$ will be the center of similitude for both the two circles. Thus, $P$ will be intersection of two common tangents to both circles. It is pretty clear that $C$ is not the center of similitude for both the circles.

Comment: Because $BC$ is not tangent to both the circles

Comment: I am extremely sorry but could you please prove why if two common tangents meet, the centre of similitude will be necessary that point? (I am really sorry)

Comment: Are you aware of 'homothety'? Look it up in the internet, you will find your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. If I stretch the tangents of the smaller circle, I will also see that they are tangent to the larger circle, isn't that it? And also that $C$,$D$ and $E$ lie in a line? Since C and D lie on a line?

Comment: yes and that line is the angle bisector of the $\angle ACB$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $C,D,E$ can never be collinear.

The reason is that $CD$ is an angle bisector and $CE$ is a median, they will only coincide when triangle $ABC$ is isosceles where $CA=CB$. However since $\angle CAB=90$ degrees, $CA$ and $CB$ cannot be equal.

**To solve your problem:**

[image]

First $AH=4$ by Pythagorean on the blue triangle. Next $HB=4\sqrt{5}$ by Pythagorean on triangle $HAB$.

Notice the two green triangles are similar with ratio $1:4$ so $B,H,G$ are collinear, further more $HG:GB=1:4$. Therefore $GB={16\over 5}\sqrt{5}$.

Now since $FB^2=BG\times BH=64$, we know $FB=8$.

Let $CH=CF=x$.

We know $${1\over 2}(x+4)\cdot 8 = S_{ABC}=S_{CDA}+S_{CDB}+S_{ADB}={1\over 2}(x+4)\cdot 1 + {1\over 2}(x+8)\cdot 1 + {1\over 2}\cdot4\cdot8$$ where $S$ denotes area.

Simplify,
$$8x+32=2x+12+32, x=2$$

Therefore $AC=6$

Comment: Your explanation was extremely intuitive and very simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The points $C$, $D$, $E$ are of course not collinear.

We are looking for $a:=|AC|$. Project $D$ orthogonally to $D'\in A\vee B$ and to $D''\in A\vee C$. Then
$$|AD''|=|D'D|=\sqrt{5^2-3^2}=4\ .$$
Let $\angle(ACD)=:\alpha$. Then $\angle(ACB)=2\alpha$. From the figure we obtain $$\tan\alpha={1\over a-4},\qquad\tan(2\alpha)={8\over a}\ ,$$
which leads to a quadratic equation for $a$ with solutions ${10\over3}$ and $6$. As ${10\over3}<4$ we necessarily have $a=6$.

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could give a diagram. I am completely a novice when it comes to projective geometry so I really do not understand what projecting orthogonally means.

Comment: Thanks! A very simple trigonometric solution.